Floating Placeholder in TextBox ASP.NET 4.0
I'm new to programming and I don't know complicated things. But I want to add small features to my site. Is there an easy way to move theplaeholder up when something is typed into the text box?
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <table class="w-100">
        <tr>
            <td><asp:TextBox ID="floatingInput" runat="server" class="form-control"  TextMode="SingleLine" placeholder="Email"></asp:TextBox></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td><asp:TextBox ID="floatingPassword" runat="server" class="form-control" TextMode="Password" placeholder="Password"></asp:TextBox></td>
         </tr>
     </table>
</form>

I have searched this on internet but I couldn't find like the way my code is written. I couldn't integrate those solutions to my code.

What you need is to create a separate element with a placeholder content and then control it's position when textbox is empty or not.
Simple example in plan html:


.text-box {
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px;
}
    
.text-box input {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
}
    
.text-box label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 12px;
  left: 10px;
  color: #aaa;
  pointer-events: none;
}
    
.text-box input:focus ~ label,
.text-box input:not(:placeholder-shown) ~ label {
  top: -20px;
  left: 10px;
}
<div class="text-box">
  <input placeholder=" ">
  <label>Some placeholder</label>
</div>



You can then customize the exact placeholder behavior, for example by adding a smooth transition or different colors for different states.

Thank you for your answer but I need to use asp:TextBox, I can't use input for this project. Isn't there any features for asp:TextBox? Or how can I implement your example in asp:TextBox tag?

@BeyzaNurKarakaya I guess you can just replace input by asp:TextBox

Thanks a lot. Then I will use this version

@BeyzaNurKarakaya If you think this answer is correct, please mark it as accepted.

You can use javascript for this.
In asp.net core 6 project with css library Bootstrap 5; I am using floating Input like that
<div class="form-floating mb-3">
  <input type="email" 
         class="form-control" 
         id="floatingInput" 
         placeholder="name@example.com">
  <label for="floatingInput">Email address</label>
</div>

Also you can write label manually.

Thanks for your answer. But I need to use asp:TextBox for login controls. How can I implement your example to my project? Because you are using div, input for that. I'm confused

asp.net 4 is very old version. My suggestıon to new developers as you write c# and asp.net with latest or supperted versions. But ı will looking for asp.net 4 still.

Yes, I know :( But my mentor said me use 4.0 for this project. I will try to use your version like with input. Thank you so much
